# How to get "Correct enter the maze" without getting "sorry, please try again"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
password = "nothing"  
tries = 0

while password != "secret":
    tries = tries + 1
    password = input("What is the secret password? ")
    print("sorry, please try again. ")
    if tries == 3:  
        print("You have been locked out")
        exit()


print("Correct! Enter the maze!")
```

when i write the correct password i get this in return

> What is the secret password? secret.

sorry, please try again.
Correct! Enter the maze

Comment: There are couple of issues with your code. The statement `print("sorry, please try again. ")` is always executed. To leave the `while` loop when `tries == 3` you should use `break` instead of `exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

Python has no do-while, so one of ways to do similar thing is

```
password = ""  
tries = 0

while True:
    password = input("What is the secret password? ")
    if password == "secret":
        break
    print("sorry, please try again. ")
    tries += 1
    if tries == 3:  
        print("You have been locked out")
        exit()
    
print("Correct! Enter the maze!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
password = "nothing"  
tries = 0

while password != "secret":
    tries = tries + 1
    password = input("What is the secret password? ")
    if password == "secret":
        break
    else:
        print("sorry, please try again. ")
        if tries == 3:  
            print("You have been locked out")
            exit()


print("Correct! Enter the maze!")
```

If you do not want the password to be seen, you can use the following library
[getpass()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass)

example:

```
import getpass


p = getpass.getpass(prompt='What is the secret password? ')
  
if p.lower() == 'secret':
    print('Correct! Enter the maze!')
else:
    print('sorry, please try again.')
```

Comment: !!! THANKS, i gotta exam the code and see where i was wrong!!! :D